# Can I do a toggling loop with Javascript alone?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple HTML and Javascript, and it works very well. My question is, is there a way to do it with loops?

I don't want to use jQuery -- just plain Javascript, please!

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="r" onclick="func();" id="r1">
    <input type="radio" name="r" onclick="func();" id="r2">
    <input type="radio" name="r" onclick="func();" id="r3">
    <input type="radio" name="r" onclick="func();" id="r4">
</form>

<div id="sq" style="    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
    display: none;"></div>
<div id="ci" style="    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #555;
    display: none;></div>
<div id="tr" style="    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #888;
    display: none;></div>

<script>
var r1 = document.getElementById("r1");
var r2 = document.getElementById("r2");
var r3 = document.getElementById("r3");

var sq = document.getElementById("sq");
var ci = document.getElementById("ci");
var tr = document.getElementById("tr");

var el = [sq, ci, tr];
var rs = [r1, r2, r3];



function func() {
    if(r1.checked) {
        sq.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        sq.style.display = "none";
    }
    if(r2.checked) {
        ci.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        ci.style.display = "none";
    }
    if(r3.checked) {
        tr.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        tr.style.display = "none";
    }


}
</script>
```

You can check it out on [codepen here](https://codepen.io/ahmet-akdeniz/pen/LjbqGO?editors=0110).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event listeners. I refactored your code a bit:

```js
const colors = ['black', '#777', '#BBB', 'white'];
const area = document.querySelector('div'); // find the <div> element
// find all <input type="radio"> elements
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach((input, index) => {
  // add an event listener to the click event
  input.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // set the <div>'s background color
    area.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="r">
<input type="radio" name="r">
<input type="radio" name="r">
<input type="radio" name="r">

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
   if (rs[i].checked) {
     el[i].style.display = "block";
   } else {
     el[i].style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks man i did learn how to use for loop correct from your answer but sorry in my case it doesn't work